# blank page on github pages -undefined root in publish project react vite on gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

my proje with react and vite succusfully run on localhost when publish it to gh-pages cannot recognize root to show my project
i follow this way:

package.jason

```
{
  "homepage": "https://ZohreScript.github.io/RickMortyEpisodes/",
  "name": "my-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
```

vite.config.js

```
       export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/RickMortyEpisodes/',
})
```

and install gh-pages an run deploy  but not working

index.html

```
     <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>rick and morthy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>




main.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

    import App from './App.jsx'
    import './index.css'
    
    ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
    )
```